# Problems with inductional proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction

Could someone help with how to approach this proof:

"For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ let the function f(n) be defined by $$f(n)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n 2^k$$

Prove by induction that $$f(n)=2^{n+1}-1$$

applies for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$"

I guess that the "Strong induction" should be used here. I tried:

1. Basic step: $n_0$ holds since $f(0)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^0 2^k=2^{n+1}-1=1$
2. Inductional step: We assume that $f(k)$ holds for $0,1,2...n$
3. For $n>0$ we thereby have $f(n+1)=f(n)+f(n-1)$. According the the induction assumption we have $f(n+1)=2^{n+1}-1+2^n-1$

But I'm kind of stuck here. Not sure how to proceed...

Comment: Hint:  show that $f(n+1)=2f(n)+1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the inductive step you have:

$$f(n+1) = \sum_{k=0}^{n+1} 2^k = 2^{n+1} + \sum_{k=0}^{n} 2^k = 2^{n+1} + 2^{n+1} - 1 = 2^{n+2} - 1$$